# new item vs exiting item recognition in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm practicing angularjs using an inventory app. The application has two different buttons that bring up the same modal window, one is to edit an existing product, and the other is to add a new product.

My logic is working because I can add new products and edit existing ones; however, I'm trying to log some stuff to the console and that doesn't appear to be working correctly.  Can someone please review my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Below is the specific code, I have the entire code in codepen http://codepen.io/andresq820/pen/LWGKXW

AngularJS Code

```
  $scope.editProduct = function(item){       

    if(item.code.typeof = 'undefined'){
      console.log('new item');
      $scope.item.code = item.code;
      $scope.item.description = item.description;
      $scope.item.in = item.amount;
      $scope.item.out = 0;
      $scope.item.createdOn = Date.now();
      $scope.items.push($scope.item);
      $scope.item = {};
    } else {
      console.log('new item');
      console.log(item);
      console.log(item.type);
      console.log($scope.item.type);
      var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
      console.log(index);
      $scope.items[index].code = item.code;
      console.log($scope.items[index].code);
      $scope.items[index].description = item.description;
      console.log($scope.items[index].description);

      if($scope.item.type == 'in'){
        console.log($scope.item.type);
        $scope.items[index].in += $scope.item.amount;
      } else if($scope.item.type == 'out'){
        console.log($scope.item.type);
        $scope.items[index].out += $scope.item.amount;
      }
      item = {};            
    }        
  };
```

HTML Modal Code

```
<!-- Edit Item Modal-->                        
        <div class="modal fade" id="editItemModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{title(item.code)}}</h4>
                </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="myEditForm" ng-submit="editProduct(item)">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="code">Code:</label>
                        <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" class="form-control" name="code" id="code" 
                        ng-model="item.code" ng-disabled="false">    
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="description">Description:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" ng-model="item.description" required>  
                        <span ng-show="myEditForm.description.$touched && myEditForm.description.$invalid">The description is required.</span>   
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="99999" size="5" maxlength="5" class="form-control" name="amount" id="amount" 
                        ng-model="item.amount" integer>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group" ng-show="displayRadioBtns">
                        <label for="radio">Type:</label>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-model="item.type" value="in">In</label>
                            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-model="item.type" value="out">Out</label>
                        </div>
                    </div> 

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="close()" value="Close" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit" />
            </div>                
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `if(item.code.typeof = 'undefined')` that is an assignment not a comparison, which will always result in false, since `undefined` is falsey. Also did you mean `item.code typeof` or do you actually have a property named `typeof`

Comment: you need to check like this if(item.code.typeof == undefined)

Comment: you don't really need to `console.log(item)` then `console.log(item.type)`
add them together in the same line as `console.log(item, item.type)` if you really need to

Comment: Embarrassing rookie mistake, thanks for pointing that out.  Can you please show me an example what you are referring to with the item.code typeof?